# Low Level vs High Level Development

Tags: kernel

I really want to start working in OS development, particularly kernel development, with the Open Source Darwin Project - building my own Mac-like operating system, however I am simply not experienced enough to work in the black art of kernel development - I'm constantly deterred by comments : "your code has to be close to spectacular" , "You need to be a programming veteran to write in kernel space"

So I Have tried to find other projects. I am working at CryENGINE 3 at the moment, but I just can't get into the API's as I'm constantly wanting to start kernel development.

I have no experience in user-land programs, however I have researched and created small assembly based programs.

Note: I'm 17 years old.

Are there any projects you can recommend me starting, so I can get some experience for user-land applications? I find it almost impossible to build something revolutionary.

I have Experience with C, C++ , C# , Java , Haskell , Ruby , Lua and ASM.

Plus: What's the chance of creating a business out of software development?

Comment: Just to add, I have Experience with C, C++ , C# , Java , Haskell , Ruby , Lua and ASM. I wish I have an idea of what to do with them!

Comment: Don't be put off by the comments. You can contribute on many levels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you really do have to be that good to make real contributions to a serious, consumer-grade kernel.

However, that doesn't mean that you have to be that good to play around with the kernel code and learn how it works.  You can start on that at any time, and it'll be a good learning experience.  Just don't expect it to be easy to understand, especially at first.

Comment: Thanks. I hope I can get soo good to make it Consumer-grade.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Good luck in your endeavors, then.  If that's what you want, you've got at least [ten years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) of study and hard work ahead of you.  But it's worth it if becoming a good coder is a serious goal for you.  And you've got a bunch of us here who've already put in our ten years and then some to help out, so feel free to ask questions when you run into stuff you don't understand.